# How to concatenate and output various video bitrates and a standalone audio file?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to concatenate and output various video bitrates and a standalone audio file in `ffmpeg`?

My requirement is:

1. I have 4 input files.
2. Need to stitch all 4 files into single segment.
3. Need output with four different video bit rates: 500k, 800k 1000k 1500k
4. Along with that I need to extract only audio from stitched file.

So my output will be 4 different video bitrate + 1 audio only file.

Comment: I had to update this question with details from another of your questions. Please always provide enough details so an accurate answer can be provided. Otherwise you'll get ignored or you'll get an answer that isn't what you want to do (like your last question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tee muxer

Most efficient method is to use the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee) (more [examples](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs#Teepseudo-muxer)) to avoid unnecessarily encoding the audio for each output, but it is complicated to use:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][aud];[v]split=4[v0][v1][v2][v3]" -map "[v0]" -b:v:0 500k -map "[v1]" -b:v:1 800k -map "[v2]" -b:v:2 1000k -map "[v3]" -b:v:3 1500k -map "[aud]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f tee "[select=\'v:0,aud\':movflags=faststart]500.mp4|[select=\'v:1,aud\':movflags=faststart]800.mp4|[select=\'v:2,aud\':movflags=faststart]1000.mp4|[select=\'v:3,aud\':movflags=faststart]1500.mp4|[select=aud:movflags=faststart]audio.m4a"
```

This example method doesn't perform two-passes which you should do when using your old school method of manually choosing the bitrate for non-streaming outputs. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

## simpler but less efficient method

You can do a much less complicated command but it will be less efficient because it will separately encode the audio for each output. Possibly worth the tradeoff of less complexity.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a];[v]split=4[v0][v1][v2][v3];[a]asplit=4[a0][a1][a2][a3]" -map "[v0]" -map "[a0]" -b:v 500k -movflags +faststart 500.mp4 -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 800k -movflags +faststart 800.mp4 -map "[v2]" -map "[a2]" -b:v 1000k -movflags +faststart 1000.mp4 -map "[v3]" -map "[a3]" -b:v 1500k -movflags +faststart 1500.mp4
```

But since you're wanting to target a specific bitrate you should perform two passes:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v];[v]split=4[v0][v1][v2][v3]" -map "[v0]" -b:v 500k -pass 1 -passlogfile 500 -f mp4 /dev/null -map "[v1]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 800k -pass 1 -passlogfile 800 -f mp4 /dev/null -map "[v2]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 1000k -pass 1 -passlogfile 1000 -f mp4 /dev/null -map "[v3]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 1500k -pass 1 -passlogfile 1500 -f mp4 /dev/null
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a];[v]split=4[v0][v1][v2][v3];[a]asplit=5[a0][a1][a2][a3][a4]" -map "[v0]" -map "[a0]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 500k -pass 2 -passlogfile 500 -movflags +faststart 500.mp4 -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 800k -pass 2 -passlogfile 800 -movflags +faststart 800.mp4 -map "[v2]" -map "[a2]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 1000k -pass 2 -passlogfile 1000 -movflags +faststart 1000.mp4 -map "[v3]" -map "[a3]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 1500k -pass 2 -passlogfile 1500 -movflags +faststart 1500.mp4 -map "[a4]" -movflags +faststart audio.m4a
```

If you're using Windows replace `/dev/null` with `NUL` in the examples above.